# How to show pages visited during sessions marked with a custom variable in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I embed custom links into each resume I send out, so I can see who as clicked on the links. I then take the custom value (passed through a url parameter) and pass it into Google Analytics as a session level custom variable. What I want to do is create a report that will show me all the typical information I can normally see (pages visited, time, etc), but filtered down by custom variables. i.e. I want to see that people form company X have looked at these parts of my website. I've been reading through all the documentation and feel like a custom report is the right way to go, but I'm not really sure. Any suggestions, links, instructions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en-GB). Play around with some configuration like the following:

[image: sample custom report]